# How can I tell if a sent message is the author's first?

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I'm currently making a bot that welcomes new users by sending a message right after the author's very first message. To clarify:

1. User joins
2. User sends first message
3. Function is called

How can I determine if the author has sent a message in the guild before?
My only idea at the moment is just to add a row for each new member (sqlite), and when they sent a message, the row will be deleted and the bot can welcome the user.

Comment: Yeah you need a database for that, I don't think discord keeps the count of how many messages you send in each guild, at least I didn't find anything looking in discord.js docs

Comment: But it does keep track of all the messages in channels.

Comment: @Giuliopime Can you make that an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah you need a database for that, I don't think discord keeps the count of how many messages you send in each guild, at least I didn't find anything looking in discord.js docs.

Answer (score 1):

Luckily we can fetch all channels, and then fetch messages from the channels:

```js
client.on('message', async message => {
  let totalUserMessages = 0;
  let txtChannels = Array.from(message.guild.channels.cache.filter(c => c.type === 'text').values());
  for (var i = 0; i < txtChannels.length; i++) {
    let channel = txtChannels[i];
    let messages = await channel.messages.fetch();
    let userMessages = messages.filter(m => m.author.id === message.author.id);
    let numOfMessages = Array.from((userMessages).values()).length;
    console.log(numOfMessages);
    totalUserMessages += numOfMessages;
  }

  console.log(totalUserMessages);
  if (totalUserMessages === 1) {
    // do stuff here
  }
});
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but wouldn't using a database be faster than this? The guild has over one million messages that it would have to loop through - see the [comparison here](https://jsben.ch/gAOJK).

Comment: Of course it would - I'd use a database as well. I just tried to come up with a solution for the problem. Sadly, there is no member.firstMessage, and message.member.lastMessage just returns the current message.